# Making sense of matrix calculus involving matrices

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

In matrix calculus, we can calculate scalar by matrix derivative or matrix by scalar derivatives, according to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Derivatives_with_matrices).

Where do these formulae come from? What I'm confused about is how this is related to ordinary multi-variable differentiation? For example, given a matrix to scalar function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n \times m} \to \mathbb{R}$, in what sense is the result a $m \times n$ matrix?

Is this related to treating matrices as vectors of dimension $n \times m$, using matrix norm to measure distance on the vector space of matrices? However, shouldn't the resulting derivative linear map of type $\mathbb{R}^{n \times m} \to \mathbb{R}$? Why is it $\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$?

A detailed derivation of the formulae would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, lets look at the general definition of a differential $df$ on normed spaces, for $f:\mathbb{S}\to\mathbb{P}$
$$f(x+h)=f(x)+df(x,h)+o(||h||_S)$$
where the differential $df(x,h)$ is linear and continuous in $h$.

Lets look at $\mathbb{S}=\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{P}=\mathbb{R}^n$.
Then any linear operator $\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ can be represented by some matrix $\in \mathbb{R^{n\times m}}$ (i.e. by matrix-vector multiplication). Lets denote this matrix $A$. So out differential in this case becomes
$$df(x,h)=A(x)h$$
We call $A(x)$ a derivative (remeber $df$ is a differential).

Now we take $\mathbb{S}=\mathbb{R}^{n\times m},\mathbb{P}=\mathbb{R}$. But we also equip this $\mathbb{S}$ with the scalar product $B\cdot C=\sum_{i,j}B_{i,j}C_{i,j}$. This is basically the same as taking $\mathbb{S}=\mathbb{R}^{nm}$ with the standard dot product. Then any linear operator $L: \mathbb{S}\to\mathbb{P}$ can be represented as $L(h)=D\cdot h$ where $D$ is some matrix $\in \mathbb{S}$.

So in this case the differential $df$ can be represented as
$$df(x,h)=A(x)\cdot h$$
We call $A(x)$ a derivative. So $A(x)$ in both cases can even be the same (tables of numbers), but they are used differently.

Small example:
$$f(x)=Ax,\ A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m},\ x\in\mathbb{R}^m,\ f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$$
$$df(x,dx)=Adx$$
$$\frac{df(x)}{dx}=A$$

$$g(x)=A\cdot x,\ A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m},\ x\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m},\ g:\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}\to\mathbb{R}$$
$$dg(x,dx)=A\cdot dx$$
$$\frac{dg(x)}{dx}=A$$
As you see the derivatives of $f$ and $g$ are the same, but they represent different things.

In general we can define a derivative when we can represent linear operators $\mathbb{S}\to\mathbb{P}$ with some product on $\mathbb{S}$. For $\mathbb{S}$ Hilbert space and $\mathbb{P}$ its field we can always use [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem) to get such a representation. In this case a derivative will be always an element from the input space $\mathbb{S}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! One thing I still want to point out is in matrix calculus, scalar-by-matrix derivative $\frac{dy}{dX}$ of dimension $m \times n$ will give the result of dimension $n \times m$. Why is that?

Comment: Moreover, why can we replace the $\mathbb{R}^{n \times m} \to \mathbb{R}$ with a matrix using Riesz representation theorem? When we evaluate a complicated matrix differentiation, won't the dimensional analysis fail?

Comment: Also just in case other people are also confused like me, after I did some search, the inner product that @Koncopd talks about is Frobenius inner product (and its induced norm called Frobenius norm).

Comment: Just to clarify what I mean by dimensional analysis fail. I would expect $\frac{dy}{dX} X$ to return a real number. However, if we have $\frac{dy}{dX}$ return a matrix of transpose dimension, $\frac{dy}{dX} X$ will be a square matrix. How is this fine?

Comment: Actually as i wrote, the order dimensions of a derivative and the derivative iself are not important, the important thing is differential. You can also take, for example, $df(x,h)=\operatorname{tr}(A(x)^Th)$, it is the same as $A(x)\cdot h$, and you call $A(x)^T$ derivative (with dimensions $m\times n$ now). Some authors prefer this trace formula for defining derivative instead of Frobenius product, but the differential stays the same, of course.

Comment: About the choice of Frobenius norm - all norms on finite-dimensional linear spaces are equivalent, so the choice of scalar product induced norm is natural.

Comment: Again, you don't need to apply you matix derivative in the only way as matrix multiplication $\frac{dy}{dX}X$. It always depends on the definition of derivative for the spaces involved and actually the differential defines how exactly you apply you derivative.

Comment: Also not that while the chain rule for differentials is always the same $d(f\circ g)(x,dx)=df(g(x),dg(x,dx))$, the chain rule for derivatives can look differently from space to space. Look here for an example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4035579/composite-function-gradient/4038098#4038098 .

Comment: I replied through chat, are you able to see it? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120271/discussion-between-rui-liu-and-koncopd