# how to do the derivative of least squares objective in vector form?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vectors, matrix-calculus, least-squares

Below we have the least squares objective function in vector form. Assume dimension of $x$ is $m \times n$, $W$ is $n \times 1$ and $y$ is $m \times 1$. So $J$ is $1 \times 1$ a scalar. $T$ below is the transpose.

$$ J=\frac{1}{m}(xW -y)^{T}(xW-y) $$

Let $A =xW-y$, then $$ J=\frac{1}{m}A^{T}A$$ $$\frac{dJ}{dA}=\frac{2}{m}A$$  $$\frac{dA}{dW}=x .$$

By chain rule:

$$ \frac{dJ}{dw}=\frac{dJ}{dA}\frac{dA}{dW}=\frac{2}{m}Ax .$$

Obviously if we do this, the dimensions don't match up, since $A$ is $m \times 1$ and $x$ is $m \times n$. Instead, the answer should be $$\frac{dJ}{dw}=\frac{2}{m}x^{T}A .$$

My question is, how do we know the convention in this case? Can someone point me to how we should do the chain rule in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For differential calculus involving matrices it is more convenient to use differentials instead of derivatives. You can find the rules for differentials in [Practical Guide to Matrix Calculus for Deep Learning by Andrew Delong](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.304.5533) or in the book "Matrix algebra" by Abadir & Magnus.

I will show you how to get the derivative of $J$ using notation and rules from the paper by Delong. Delong's paper doesn't have the chain rule for differentials but it is
$$d(f\circ g)(x, dx)=df(g(x),dg(x,dx))$$
You can look [Composite function gradient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4035579/composite-function-gradient/4038098#4038098) for a proof sketch.

So using the rules (10), (12) from the paper
$$dJ(A,dA)=d(\frac{1}{m}A^TA)=\frac{1}{m}dA^TA+\frac{1}{m}A^TdA=\frac{1}{m}(dA)^TA+\frac{1}{m}A^TdA=\frac{2}{m}A^TdA$$
$$dA(x,dx)=d(xW-y)=dxW$$
$$d(A(W),dW)=d(xW-y)=xdW$$
By the chain rule, the rule (6) and the fact that $v^Tu=v\cdot u$ for vectors $v,u$
$$dJ(x,dx)=dJ(A(x),dA(x,dx))=\frac{2}{m}A(x)^TdA(x,dx)=\frac{2}{m}(xW-y)^TdxW=$$
$$=\frac{2}{m}(xW-y)\cdot dxW=\frac{2}{m}(xW-y)W^T\cdot dx$$
$$dJ(W,dW)=J(A(W),dA(W,dW))=\frac{2}{m}(xW-y)\cdot xdW=\frac{2}{m}x^T(xW-y)\cdot dW$$
From these and the rule (17)
$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial x}=\frac{2}{m}(xW-y)W^T$$
$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial W}=\frac{2}{m}x^T(xW-y)$$

Comment: Thank you so much for this! The paper was just what I needed on. Just one question, when you write differentials in the form of dJ(A,dA), do we interpret this as the differential of J is a function of A and dA? Thanks again!!!!

Comment: Yes. Also you can interpret it as the differential with argument $dA$ (remember that a differential is always a linear map in $dA$) of the function J of argument $A$ (or at a point $A$).

Answer (score 0):

Not that it matters mathematically, but using capital letters for vectors and lower case for matrices is unusual. Nevertheless, a few hints:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial W_j}(A^TA)=\frac{\partial}{\partial W_j}\sum_{i} A_i^2 =\sum_{i}2 A_i\frac{\partial A_i}{\partial W_j}=2 A_i \nabla A_{ij} $

Rearrange $A_i \nabla A_{ij}=\nabla A_{ij} A_i=\nabla A^T_{ji} A_i$ to render an equivalent expression that has a more obvious connection to matrix notation.

In matrix form: $ \nabla (A^T A)=2(\nabla A)^TA$

In your problem $A=(xW-y)$ and $\nabla A=x$

$ \nabla A^2=2(\nabla A)^T A=2x^TA$